# How to access CouchDB using JavaScript? SOP errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, couchdb, same-origin-policy

I'm new to Couch DB. I installed CouchDB on my home folder on our university server that looks like...

```
http://servername.com/home/users/roby
```

The Db is running on port 1234 and it is working great. I was able to populate the DB using the Couch4J driver for Java using an SSH tunnel from my machine.

I'm developing a web application that needs the data stored on the db. Suppose I've an index.html file located at

```
http://servername.com/home/users/roby/public_html/index.html
```

that is translated to

```
http://servername.com/~roby/index.html
```

When issuing a simple request I got weird errors such as

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxxxxxx:1234/. 
Origin http://servername.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The code I'm using to try to get some response from the DB is the following

```
$.couch.urlPrefix = "http://xxxxxxx:1234";

$.couch.info({
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

RM

Answer (score 3):

You have three choices.

1. You can proxy CouchDB with, say Nginx, so you can serve html from same port as you serve CouchDB.
2. You can serve html from CouchDB itself, by attaching it to a document (easiest way is to use CouchApp or alike).
3. Finally You can enable jsonp responses in CouchDB and add `calback` param to query, jQuery has support for jsonp responses.

If you cant change server configuration, options 1 and 3 are out. As for number two, you can at the lowest level add attachments using put requests:

```
curl -X PUT http://xxxx:1234/dbname/docname/index.html --data-binary @index.html -H "Content-Type: text/html"
```

You would need to upload file after every change, so it is not really practical to do by hand. There are tools such as [CouchApp](http://couchapp.org) or [Kenso](http://kan.so/) to help you with that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I didn't have rights to install CouchApp on my server? How could I attach manually HTML docs to CouchDB docs? I just need three views, that I already created with Futon. Do you suggest to proxy in this case?

Comment: @RMinelli Hi, I've expanded my answer, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try that, by now I put this as a secondary work  in my development!